# Numbers 31 questions

Tags: numbers

Numbers 31 is a hard chapter to process, for a number of reasons, so please feel free to offer any support. God commanded the captives to be executed, and I understand they were deeply rooted in horrible pagan sexual practices/sacrifices and their promiscuity could lead some Israelite men into sin and negatively affect their community/culture, so they should not have been taken captive.

1. The virgins girls that were kept alive - I am assuming they didn't actually have a mid-wife perform a vaginal exam, right, so they just kept very young, pre-pubescent girls to be servants?  Were some of these captives eventually given as wives to some of the Israelites, when they were of age?
2. The rest of the captives, older women and male children, were to be executed. I am assuming that would be tens of thousands needing to be executed. Does anyone know how they performed that mass execution, and was it done humanely?

Comment: You probably should ask this question at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/ or http://judaism.stackexchange.com/ - you will be able to get a better answer there. Biblical Hermeneutics is about interpreting the text itself (i.e. Hebrew language study, meaning of words, etc), not about discussing Judaism/Christianity in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a way to exterminate people humanely, but that doesn't seem to be the point of the story of Numbers 31. The point of the story is to provide rules (verses 15-30) and precedent (verses 31 through the end of the chapter) for how to dispose of the spoils of a conflict that involves חרם (*herem*), complete destruction. As such, it does impose some degree of discipline and restraint on this type of conflict, which  was sometimes inevitable in the ancient world. This might have been a great improvement over previous practice. I think that we need to leave it at that. This isn't law that is applicable today.

To understand the depth of the enmity between the Israelites and Midianites refer to Judges 6, where the Midianites are represented as marauders from the Arabian peninsula who join with the Amelikites, a merciless arch-enemy, in attacking the settled Israelites. They were an existential threat.

The story in Numbers 31 is presented in schematic form that does not allow us to reconstruct historical detail. There are no extra-textual findings to shed light on which historical battle this was and what actually happened. Even the identity of the Midianites in Numbers 31 is not completely clear. Bilaam Ben Baor is mentioned among those put to death in verse 9, but he wasn't a Midianite, or even a Moavite. Also , it appears from the story that the Midianites were completely destroyed. However, in Judges 6 they are back in force. Jethro the Kenite was not only a Midianite but a priest or prince of Midian and the Kenites were an allied tribe from the time of Moses's marriage to Ziporra, one of Jethro's daughters, to the exile of Judah.

Answer (score 0):

> Were some of these captives eventually given as wives to some of the Israelites, when they were of age?

Deuteronomy 22:10-14 describes the general scenario where the Israelites wage a battle against their (non-Jewish) enemies, and what the laws are regarding an Isrselite man who is attracted to a female captive.  What is interesting here is that the Talmud in Kiddushin 21b mentions that even a married woman can be taken captive, in addition to young virgins.  As Rashi and other commentators note, the procedure which the Israelite man must follow is strongly geared towards his entering into a *marriage* with the female captive.  She is required to shave her head, let her nails grow, and mourn her father and mother for an entire month before the Israelite man is permitted to cohabit with her.  The commentators suggest that these measures are taken to remove the physical beauty of the woman from the equation.  This ritual can be viewed as a sort of cooling off period, designed to minimize the chance that the Israelite male would enter into a heat of the moment lustful relationship.  Rather, the intention is that a Jewish marriage should be the outcome.

With regard to why only virgin women were acceptable in Numbers 31, one explanation is that the adult Midianite women were considered so morally perverse that no ritual could render them suitable as Jewish wives.  The procedure described in Deuteronomy 22, according to Rashi, applies only to *optional* battles which Israel might wage.  But as Numbers 31:2 describes, the war against the Midianites came as a direct order from G-d:

> בנְקֹם נִקְמַת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵאֵת הַמִּדְיָנִים אַחַר תֵּאָסֵף אֶל עַמֶּיךָ:
>   And let the Children of Israel take a vengeance against the Midianites; afterwards you (Moses) shall be gathered unto your people.

There is a concept in Judaism that children below the age of puberty are not considered responsible for their actions.  It is possible that this is the reason that even Midianite women below a certain age were considered acceptable.  But in any case, we can presume that these virgin captives were being taken as wives.

> Does anyone know how they performed that mass execution, and was it done humanely?

I don't have a reference for the second half of your question.  I can suggest that execution was carried out by a method which would have been considered acceptable by the Sanhedrin.  The reasoning here is that the Israelites already viewed themselves as the heirs-to-be of Israel, and that the court systems which would have been in place would not be different than what would exist in Israel later on.  The four methods of execution were stoning, burning, decapitation, and strangulation.  Burning involved pouring molten lead down the person's throat and stoning should be obvious.  Some of these methods were draconian and would likely be ruled as Cruel and Unusual punishment.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. It is hard for our modern minds to understand how vicious life was not too long ago.